# Go from a String to an Array of "words" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, string, array

I need to go from a string to an array where each entry is each word on that string. For example, starting with:

```
VotePedro="Vote for Pedro"
```

I need the array:

```
Vote
For
Pedro
```

Which I should then be able to iterate over as:

```
for i in "${votePedroArray[@]}"
    do
    ## Do something
    done
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
VotePedro="Vote for Pedro"
votePedroArray=(${VotePedro})
```

Explanation:

Arrays are usually declared using parentheses. For example `votePedroArray=("Vote" "For" "Pedro")` would give you an array of length 3. And `${VotePedro}` is the same as $VotePedro in this context. To access individual array elements, you can use brackets similar to what you had for the for loop in your question. e.g. `${votePedroArray[0]}` is the first element in the array ("Vote" for this example)

Comment: Could you explain what the parentheses and the brackets do? I'm new to BASH and want to understand why this would work.

Comment: Arrays are usually declared using parentheses.

For example `votePedroArray=("Vote" "For" "Pedro")` would give you an array of length 3.

And `${VotePedro}` is the same as `$VotePedro` in this context.

To access individual array elements, you can use brackets similar to what you had for the for loop in your question. e.g. `${votePedroArray[0]}` is the first element in the array ("Vote" for this example)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: And to iterate over them:  for vote in ${votePedroArray[@]}; do echo $vote; done

Answer (score 5):

In `bash` and most other Bourne-like shells, when you leave a variable expansion unquoted, e.g. `$VotePedro`, the following steps are performed:

1. Look up the value of the variable.
2. Split the value at each block of whitespace into a list of strings. More generally, the separators are the characters in the value of the `IFS` variable; by default that's space, tab and newline.
3. Interpret each element of the list as a wildcard pattern; for each element, if the pattern matches some files, then replace that element by the list of matching file names.

Thus you can split a string into whitespace-delimited elements (assuming the default value of `IFS`) by turning off wildcard expansion and expanding a variable whose value is that string outside of quotes.

```
VotePedro="Vote for Pedro"
set -f
votePedroArray=($VotePedro)
set +f
for i in "${votePedroArray[@]}"; do …
```

You can directly do the split at the point of use; this would work even in shells such as sh that don't have arrays:

```
VotePedro="Vote for Pedro"
set -f
for i in ${votePedro}; do
  set +f
  …
done
set +f
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides breaking it on `$IFS`, you can also just break it on whatever you like:

```
set ''
while case $var in
      (* *) ;; (*)
      ! a=("$var$@")
      esac
do    set '' "${var##* }$@"
      var=${var% "$2"}
done
```

...which would allow for whitespace separated null-fields, even.